# How can I count distinct months names in a set of date values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table 'Data' and there has two field is Date_date1 and also Data_date2, and i want count it based on month.
this my database

```
Table: Data
Data_date1  Data_date2   
---------------------------------
2019-07-23  2019-01-23
2019-08-23  2019-01-24
2019-08-24  2019-02-23
2019-09-21  2019-07-23
2019-09-22  2019-09-22
2019-09-23  2019-09-23
```

and i want the results like this one

```
Month   Count_Date1     Count_Date2
Jan     0               2
Feb     0               1
July    1               1
Aug     2               0
Sep     3               9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(data_date) m
  ,SUM(d=1) d1
  ,SUM(d=2) d2 
FROM
  (SELECT 1 d, data_date1 data_date FROM my_table
   UNION
   SELECT 2, data_date2 FROM my_table
  ) x
GROUP BY m
```

Here’s some setup with which to test this query, which produces the desired results:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(data_date1  DATE NOT NULL
,data_date2  DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2019-07-23','2019-01-23'),
('2019-08-23','2019-01-24'),
('2019-08-24','2019-02-23'),
('2019-09-21','2019-07-23'),
('2019-09-22','2019-09-22'),
('2019-09-23','2019-09-23');
```

Comment: Man, that cat is fast

Comment: I hope you don’t mind me reformatting, but I wanted the beauty of your brevity to be more obvious

Comment: okay thanks,  this answer works fine also. But is it possible to change the month number to be the name of the month?

Comment: @AdityaDS Not only is possible, it's trivial!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select month(dte), sum(cnt1), sum(cnt2)
from ((select data_date1 as dte, 1 as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select data_date2, 0, 1
       from t
      )
     ) dd
group by month(dte);
```

This shows the month number rather than the month name.

If you want the month name, you would do:

```
select monthname(dte), sum(cnt1), sum(cnt2)
from ((select data_date1 as dte, 1 as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select data_date2, 0, 1
       from t
      )
     ) dd
group by monthname(dte), month(dte)
order by month(dte);
```

Comment: okay, thanks for the answer. But is it possible to change the month number to be the name of the month? may you can help?